# "Arithmetic logic unit developmental notes" vs "Arithmetic logic unit development notes"

Tags: word-choice, grammaticality

Which one is correct?

> "Arithmetic logic unit developmental notes"

vs

> "Arithmetic logic unit development notes"

And, if both are correct, what is the difference between the two phrases?

Comment: Have you looked up the difference between development and developmental? This may help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using development as noun adjunct is more common in usage.

[image: developmental_notes_vs_development_notes]

Comment: Thanks for answering, and thanks for introducing me to Ngram!